# Erro ao debugar webservice (asmx) localmente no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-service, visual-studio

Estou tentando debugar localmente um webservice (asmx) a partir do Visual Studio.
Ao tentar criar a conexão com o banco de dados, ocorre a seguinte exceção:

> Falha na solicitação da permissão de tipo
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Eu já alterei no cabeçalho da classe, incluindo a permissão:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
```

E também adicionei no Web.config:

```
<securityPolicy>
<trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

Mesmo assim, o erro permanece. O mesmo webservice está rodando sem problema na máquina de Produção.

Alguém sabe o que fazer para reverter essa situação na máquina local com o Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Apenas atualizando, encontrei o "problema". Eu abri o projeto remotamente (em rede). Depois que copiei o projeto para máquina local, consegui debugar sem problemas. Fica a dica.